# Append the values to the URL on Form in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, forms, get

I have a form link on multiple pages. All I need when I click on a form link  for page A it should  display as `www.form.com?referrer=Page A` on URL  and when I submit the form, I have created a hidden field `referrer`, when I received it on my email on the referrer field it should show "page A".

I have this HTML code which was working fine however, I do not want to do it manually on every page, as soon as a user clicks on the form link or received the form it should automatically updated:

```
<a target="_blank" title="Click Here" href="https://myform.com/forms/land_discount?referrer= Beach Club">
```

Here is the JavaScript for my Form:

[Discount Form](https://hideawayholidaysptyltd.formstack.com/forms/land_discount)

Comment: Can you clarify this a bit? Are you saying that if you click on this link `https://myform.com/forms/test`, it would append automatically to `https://myform.com/forms/test?referrer=Whatever+Page+this+is` or would it be `https://myform.com/forms/test?referrer=Game+Form` or `https://myform.com/forms/test?referrer=Online+Form` or something else?

Comment: Hi Rasckatt..I have edit my Question..if i have click a form on page A..on url it should "www.form.com?referrer=Page A" ..I think the first option

Comment: I don't see any forms in your code.

Comment: So it would read the URI of the page and append the page to the `?referrer=page/name`?

Comment: @Rasclatt Yes..that is the expected result i want

Comment: @ECMAScript i have updated my Question on JavaScript Code..you can check my form[link] there..

Answer (score 0):

See if this is what you are trying to do:

```
// I'm going to use jQuery, it's easier for me
$(document).ready(function(){
    // I used a class so it doesn't do it to every <a> tag
    $('a.use_refer').click(function(e){
        // Stop the button from submitting normally
        e.preventDefault();
        // Create a new url
        // You may or may not want to use encodeURIComponent() on the path value
        var newUrl  =   $(this).attr('href')+'?referrer='+document.location.pathname;
        // Go to the new page
        window.location = newUrl;
    });
});
</script>

<a href="https://myform.com/forms/land_discount" title="Online Form" class="use_refer">Click Here</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you `Page A` is the last directory of the path. And wrap this for when the DOM is ready.

Note the changes to the HTML with the addition of the `id=` tag.

On "Page A"

HTML:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://myform.com/forms/js.php/test"></script>
 <noscript>
   <a href="https://myform.com/forms/test" title="Online Form">Game Form</a>
 </noscript>
```

Javascript:

```
var url = document.getElementById('formRef').getAttribute("href");
document.getElementById('formRef')
.setAttribute('href', encodeURI(url + '?referrer=' + window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)));
```

On "Landing Page"

HTML:

```
<a id="landingPage" target="_blank" title="Click Here" href="https://myform.com/forms/land_discount">
```

Javascript:

```
var href = document.getElementById('landingPage').getAttribute('href');

if(window.location.href.indexOf('referrer=') > -1){
    document.getElementById('landingPage').setAttribute('href', encodeURI(href + window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?referrer='))));
}
```

Comment: Sir;i have a htm file called "HHForm.htm"..which act as a link on my htm page(Page A) . <a target="_blank" title="Click Here"  href="../HHForm.htm"> on HHForm.htm.  i have a redirection code that points to:https://myform.com/forms/js.php/test..on your code above which section Page A or landing page to insert into?..I have put on the code but it still not given the expected result